# How increase product view size on category page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, category-attribute

I am using magento 1.9 for learning purpose. On category page i want to increase product view dimension and make the changes in list.phtml file. Also change the column count 3 in place of 4, But on category page my product image height changed according to changes i have made in list.phtml file and width remains same. 
[image: screenshot of my category page]

my previous product image dimension is 270px, 414px and new dimension is 370px, 514px. In google inspect it is showing the new dimension but product width remains same. Please guide me how can i change the product width.

Comment: the width of the element containing the image needs to be changed. In css the image width is 100% of its container. If no width is explicitly set on its parent keep going up the DOM until you find out where its being set in css

Comment: Where i can change the image container width?

Comment: in css - probably styles.css looking at your screenshot. Please do this on a development site first

Comment: Checked in css and and changed and make the changes but not working

Comment: This is nothing to do with Magento, its an css issue, please try to give width:100%,and hieght:100%

Answer (score 0):

Anyone please guide me where i can edit red highlighted dimension.
[image]

Comment: Please don't ask questions as answers

Comment: Sorry i am new with this forum. Actually i need to attach a screenshot. Can you please suggest me how can i attache a screenshot in comment box.

Comment: You can't can't have images on the comments, but a link to image will be fine. But if you have more screenshots about your question, feel free to edit the question and add as many related images you want.

Comment: Thanks Rinto for your explain. For future edits i will do the same.